# Vsto c# Word Add In Activate Document After Opening Dialog

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I am creating a word VSTO add in to add some formating options. Currently when you click on a button in my ribbon it opens a form with options using `ShowDialog()`. When the user clicks 'Apply' my form closes using `this.Close()` but focus does not return to the word document.

Using

```
Applicaton.ActiveWindow.Activate();
Applicaton.ActiveDocument.Activate();
```

did not help.

How can I return focus to the document?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use Windows API or Word functions like the [SetFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus) one.

But I think a better solution is to use the parent window handle for the [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-form-showdialog(system-windows-forms-iwin32window)) method call. In that case the focus will not be lost when the window is closed. You may construct an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) interface from the window handle, see [Window.Hwnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.hwnd).

Comment: I tried both methods, but I still cant type in the document before clicking on it.

Comment: I found the way to do this. see my answer

Comment: The right solution is to specify the parent window handle for any child window. Typically you don't have to use functions like `SetFocus` or `Activate` one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns uot that there is a `SetFocus` method on the `ActiveWindow` which I used like this:

```
formOptions.ShowDialog();
Application.ActiveWindow.SetFocus();
```

Comment: The right solution is to specify the parent window handle for any child window. Typically you don't have to use functions like `SetFocus` or `Activate` one.